# set the visibility of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a web app in which i want to use a date picker

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="documents/css/reset.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/BeatPicker.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="documents/css/demos.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="documents/css/prism.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/BeatPicker.min.js"></script>
```

these are the script and link i downloaded from the web

this is my input field where i want to use datepicker

```
<body>
     <input type="text" data-beatpicker="true"/>
</body>
```

but there is a by default button with the textbox

[image]

i used the css to remove the button by making the `visibility:hidden;`

```
    <style>
button, input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #D36161;
    border: medium none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: bold 14px arial,serif;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 72px;
}
</style>
```

but when i try to add another button it also disabled because of the stylesheet where i put `visibility:hidden`

this is my button with id
`<button id="butt">close</button>`

i edited th stylesheet like this

```
<style>
.butt{
visibility:visible;
}
</style>
```

but still it is not showing me the desired button

how can i do? i want to disable the button with textbox but visible other button

Comment: Prefix `#` when using ID selector i.e. `#butt`, closing as TYPO

Comment: dont use id as butt as it is offensive

Comment: @Mahi good one man :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a library called "**BeatPicker**".

**Before messing arrond with the css, you should read the documentation.**

To remove the 'clear' button  you will need to add the following attribute to the date input

> data-beatpicker-module="clear"

This will remove the clear button

More features are available here: http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/demos.html

Answer (score 0):

A class selector is preceded by `.`, and an ID selector is preceded by `#`. So in your code, change the selector to `#butt`, because it is the ID of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.visible {
    visibility: visible
}

button.hidden {
    visibility: hidden
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="visible">This is a visible button</button>
<button class="hidden">This is an invisible button</button>
<button>Notice that the invisible button still takes up space.</button >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

change `button, input[type="button"]` to `.beatpicker-clearButton` so you don't have this problem any more or as Adi Darachi sad add `clear` to the `data-beatpicker-module` attribute to remove the button

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<body>
<input type="text" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-position="['*','*']"  data-beatpicker-module="today,clear" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css. This will hide only the beatpicker clear buttons.

```
.beatpicker-clearButton {
   display: none;
}
```